# Python ValueError: float: Argument: . is not number on line 12

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok, so I'm new to python and I'm currently taking the python for everybody course (py4e).

Our lesson 7.2 assignment is to do the following:

> 7.2 Write a program that prompts for a file name, then opens that file and reads through the file, looking for lines of the form:
>
> ```
> X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475
> ```
>
> Count these lines and extract the floating point values from each of the lines and compute the average of those values and produce an output as shown below. Do not use the sum() function or a variable named sum in your solution.
>   You can download the sample data at http://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt when you are testing below enter mbox-short.txt as the file name.

I can't figure it out. I keep getting this error

```
ValueError: float: Argument: . is not number on line 12
```

when I run this code (see screenshot): https://gyazo.com/a61768894299970692155c819509db54 
Line 12 which is `num = float(balue) + float(num)` keeps acting up. When I remove the float from balue then I get another which says

> "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects on line 12".

Can arguments be converted into floats or is it only a string? That might be the problem but I don't know if it's true and even if it is I don't know how to fix my code after that.

Comment: No thank you. This is not a site to have your homework done for you. If you have a specific issue with your code, please see how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Would you delete the screenshot of code and replace it with code, in the question, in text format? Code as an image is not compatible with clipboards, search engines and screen-readers, and thus is not an ideal format in which to supply your work. This question may be put on hold on that basis, but if you can repair it, we can stop it closing (or we can reopen it after it is closed, if it comes to that).

Comment: Show what you’ve tried and tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. You can get better answers when you provide research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach was not so bad I would say. However, I do not get what you intended with `for balue in linez`, as this is iterating over the characters contained in linez. What you rather would have wanted float(linez). I came up with a close solution looking like this:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
print(fname)

count = 0
num = 0
with open(fname, "r") as ins:
    for line in ins:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
            num += float(line[20:])
            count += 1

print(num/count)
```

This is only intended to get you on the right track and I have NOT verified the answer or the correctness of the script, as this should be contained your homework.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is answered - I am doing the same course and I had the same error message on that exact question. It was caused by the line being read as a non float and I had to read it as

```
number =float((line[19:26]))
```

By the way, the Python environment in the course is very sensitive to spaces in strings - I just got the right code and it rejected it since I had ": " and the correct answer was ":" - just spent half an hour on colons.

Just for the sake of it, here is the answer I reached, which has been accepted as the correct one. Hope you got there in the end.

```
# Use the file name mbox-short.txt as the file name

count = 0
average = 0

filename = input("Enter file name: ")
filehandle = open(filename)

for line in filehandle:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : continue

    line = line.rstrip()
    number =float((line[19:26]))

    count = count + 1
    average = average + number

average = (average / count)
average = float(average)
print("Average spam confidence:",average)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Take input from user
fname = input("Please inser file name:")


#try and except
try:
    fhand = open(fname)
except:
    print("File can not be found", fname)
    quit()

    
#count and total

count= 0
total = 0

for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        continue

    else:
        line = line[20:]
        uline = line.upper()
        fline = float(uline)

        count = count+1
        total = total + fline
        avr = total / count

print("Average spam confidence:" ,avr )
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your problem is in fixing the slicing of the string to extract the number.

If you are looking for colon character, ":" to find the floating number,
remember you have to slice the string with +1 added to the slicing. If you do not do that you end up getting----->      :     0.8475
which is not a number.
so, slice the string with +1 added to the starting index of the string and you shall have a fix.